# Como fazer com que uma DIV preencha toda a largura disponível

Tags: html, css, div

Tenho duas divs, uma com largura fixa, 250px; que fica à esquerda, será um menu fixo, sempre à esquerda.
E outra div à direita que quero fazer com que ela fique 100%, sempre que o usuário manusear os cantos da tela, ela fiquei 100%.

Algo assim:

```
.menu{width: 250px; float: left; position;fixed}
.resto{width:100%; float:right;}
```

Answer (score 7):

Faça assim:

```
.menu{ width: 250px; float: left; background-color: blue; }
.resto{ background-color: red; overflow: hidden;}
```

Para que fique assim:

[image: Conteúdo com presença de menu]

Note que se o conteúdo tiver múltiplas linhas, ele não vai aparecer debaixo do menu. Isso é feito pelo uso do estilo `overflow: hidden`. Além disso, o conteúdo não precisa do estilo float que você usou.

### [Exemplo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7FWWE/1/)

Se não fosse pelo uso do `overflow: hidden` ficaria assim:

[image: Como ficaria sem o uso do estilo overflow hidden]

Comment: Muito obrigado Miguel, sua dica foi muito útil! :)

Comment: psss... Onde foste buscar o `position:blocked` ? _(ver: [W3C - CSS Properties - Position](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position))_ Quer uses `position:blocked` quer não, como o valor para essa propriedade é inválido, essa declaração não é interpretada pelo navegador. O resultado se removeres isso do teu código é rigorosamente o mesmo, mantendo a tua solução como válida.

Comment: @Zuul: Tomei por base a resposta do @JeffersonAlison, mas ao invés de usar `height: 100%` nas classes CSS, eu usei `overflow: hidden` na classe `resto`... não sei de onde veio o `position:blocked`. =D

Comment: Não tinha reparado que ele também tinha esse `position:blocked`, obrigado pelo feedback, já deixei comentário na resposta dele em relação a este assunto.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que assim da certo: [EXEMPLO](http://jsfiddle.net/ym6dt/)

**CSS:**

```
//Opcional para pegar 100% de altura
body, html, .menu, .resto{
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu{
    width: 250px; 
    float: left; 
    background-color: #f09; 
    position:blocked;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
    Menu Fixed com 250px
</div>
<div class="resto">
    Resto do conteudo (liquido)
</div>
```

Comment: psss... Onde foste buscar o `position:blocked` ? (ver: [W3C - CSS Properties - Position](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position)) Quer uses `position:blocked` quer não, como o valor para essa propriedade é inválido, essa declaração não é interpretada pelo navegador. O resultado se removeres isso do teu código é rigorosamente o mesmo, mantendo a tua solução como válida.

Answer (score 1):

Se queres que as `div's` alterem o tamanho consoante o manusear da tela, tens de por todas as medidas em `%`. Ou seja, esse `250px` tens de passar para `%`. Caso contrário ele vai sempre assumir esse tamanho e nunca o tamanho do ecrã.

**EDIT:**
Penso que seja isto que procuras. Tens de usar a `position` a `blocked`.
Segue JSFiddle que fiz, penso que seja a tua solução:

[JSFIDDLE com div's](http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmiguel/UUzhm/)

Comment: Na verdade, eu quero que apenas a div resto fica 100%, no caso à direita. A div com o menu não pode alterar de tamanho nem largura, ela é uma div fixa à esquerda. Será que tenho que fazer isso em javascript?

Comment: Editei o meu comentário. Dá uma olhadela

Comment: Se a largura é 100% não precisa de `float`

Comment: Pois não, apenas copiei o código do @FelipeStoker e já la vinha o `float`

Comment: Fiz a alteração. A div está aumentando 100%, teria como fazer isso também com os elementos dentro dessa div? inclusive com imagens?

Comment: Queres que as imagens também mudem de tamanho?

Comment: Isso mesmo, se possível isso também.
Talvez:

.resto img {width:100%}
?

Comment: Para ser sincero nunca experimentei :P Mas também deves ter de usar percentagens

Answer (score 0):

Você quer fazer um layout responsivo? Caso sim dê uma olhada em [bootstrap grid template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/), dessa forma você irá poder layouts responsivos facilmente.

Comment: Responsivo, acho que não seria o termo certo. Eu quero que apenas uma div seja manuseada, no caso a div resto.

Comment: Mas você quer que ela mude a característica quando as o usuário modificar o tamanho da tela do browser?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o que vc deseja é um menu lateral e o conteúdo no centro ?
Dê uma olhada no exemplo que eu fiz: http://jsfiddle.net/kLFk9/2/

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma possível solução para seu problema.

PS: position:blocked, como citado não é um valor permitido para o position.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="col1">...</div>
  <div class="col2">...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  width: 900px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

/* coluna da esquerda */
.col1 {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

/* coluna da direita */
.col2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Veja no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fellipe/qJyGV/)

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado a todos, consegui resolver.

Na div do Menu. usei como de praxe:

```
.menu{position:fixed; width:192px; z-index:10;}
.resto{float:right; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Ai, foi necessário um JS

```
function resizeHome(){
    var largura = $(window).width();
        if(largura>=*tamanho mínimo da tela (VALOR)*){
            $('.resto').css('width',($(window).width()-*largura da div menu*)+'px');
        }
}
```

Comment: poste a solução para que mais pessoas vejam...

Comment: Editei meu comentário. =D

Comment: Cara, não tem necessidade de usar javascript pra isso, da uma olhada na minha resposta.

Comment: não seria melhor colocar os tamanhos todos em % pra não precisar usar javascript?

Comment: O que acontece é que existem elementos dentro dessas divs 100%, e esses elementos precisam ficar alinhados ao centro, ou seja, esses elementos precisam de um width definido e uma margin: auto, portanto, só com % não irá funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Caso você queira utilizar o menu com com `position:fixed`, uma boa maneira seria:

```
.menu{
    width:250px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;left:0;
}
.resto{
    margin-left:250px;
}
```

#### Exemplo: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/8YxGY/)